# How to write the response to a variable (Python, Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a window using Python TKinter. In the window, the user specifies the data and clicks the "Submit" button. How to write this data into a variable?

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def show_message():
    messagebox.showinfo("musercorp sender", message.get())
 
root = Tk()
root.title("musercorp sender")
root.geometry("300x250")
 
message = StringVar()
 
message_entry = Entry(textvariable=message)
message_entry.place(relx=.5, rely=.1, anchor="c")
 
message_button = Button(text="Отправить код", command=show_message)
message_button.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")
 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `message.get()` is accessible so it already is in a variable in a way, but actually You could for example add to a list or dictionary or define a variable set it to None, then use gloabl and set variable to message.get()

Comment: Can you please help with this? I'm not very experienced.

Comment: Just say `var=message.get()` and then make it `global`.